# Voxel Remesh for imported FBX

Tags: modeling

newbie question here. I imported a FBX model and want to remesh with the Voxel remesh. However it comes with a really strange result.

Any idea why? Thanks.

[image: before]

[image: after]

Comment: It can happen that faces imported from another format are not connected to each other. Go into edit mode, vertex select mode, right click , merge , by distance

Comment: Thanks! It makes perfect sense!